# this my code i have is someone call tell me what is going wrong

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

please may someone help to fix this problem,I tried to use `spl_autoload_register` to replace auto load function

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAh2X.png)

```
function spl_autoload_register( function($class_name) {
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
                
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also [edit] your question to include the PHP version you are using.

Comment: What is the first `function` keyword doing?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to putting `function` in front of the `spl_autoload_register`. It should be as follow:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});
```

Remember, you are not creating the `spl_autoload_register` function, you're calling it. calling is as follow: `functionToCall();` You then pass an anonymous function to your `spl_autoload_register` as an argument.